# How to build clang LibTooling on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, clang, libtooling

I want to use clang's LibTooling on Mac OS X Yosemite.
Clang's docs only shows how to build clang and llvm, 
but what I need is LibTooling, not whole clang (xcode has already provided clang and llvm).
How to build LibTooling without building another clang?

Answer (score 3):

Building a tool with clang LibTooling, it is not hard.

First, you should `git clone <llvm-project>` into somewhere local.

Second, using one of the building tools, e.g., CMake, ninja, make, etc, to generate clang configuration files.

Then, write down your own code in clang/tools/ or clang-tools-extra/ and modify relating cMakeLists.txt to let the building tool know how to build your own tool.

For more specific information, you can refer to [How To Setup Clang Tooling For LLVM](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/HowToSetupToolingForLLVM.html).

I hope this answer will be helpful.

Comment: I had a heck of a time getting a project going out of the llvm source tree.  Is there a guide on this now officially on their site? I was hacking away and so did not document my steps along the way unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

`libTooling` basically gives you an access to **all** of the Clang's internals. This means that there is no such separate thing as Clang libTooling (only an internal library inside of Clang). This being said, building `libTooling` is equal to building another Clang.